# What would be suitable wiring for a 52V DC 30A 1000W e-bike?

Tags: wire, amperage, gauge

So I bought a 12AWG RW90 wire from homedepot and I think it caused my anderson pp45 connector to blow. I'm looking at the wiring for my motor and battery, and they both look like 12 gauge wires. And I'm confused, because this chart(https://www.altestore.com/diy-solar-resources/wire-sizing-tool-for-12-24-and-48-volt-dc-systems/) says that a 10 gauge is required for a 30A circuit. The motor(bafang BBSHD) is rated as a 48V30A system, so how can it use a 12 gauge wire? I'm asking all this because I need to extend the wire to connect it to a battery in a backpack I'll be carrying.

Comment: How do you ‘blow’ a connector? Did it get hot and melt?

Comment: The connector was nowhere near the motor, so yeah I think it overheated internally.

Comment: Every chart I find on google says that a 12 gauge wire can only handle 20A, yet the BBSHD motor uses a 12 gauge wire for a 30A system. What am I missing here??

Comment: If you're extending it, the extra length adds resistance, so increase the gauge to compensate. (As to the overheating, that does sound like a crimp problem)

Answer (score 5):

The ratings for wire and not exactly cut and dried, unless you're subject to electrical code for home wiring or something like that.

You can see from [this](https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm) that AWG 12 (~2mm) is okay for 41A "chassis wiring". 6' of it will drop only about 0.4V at 40A, which means you're not losing much to heating even at full rated motor current. In fact you might prefer to have a bit of heating and higher rated insulation and lighter, more flexible wire.

Your wire is rated at 90°C and has only 7 strands so it's pretty stiff. At the other end of the scale you can find super-flexible 200°C silicone wire with 680 strands or much thinner PTFE or PTFE/Kapton wire, also with a 200°C rating.

But **any of these wires** should be okay enough if you get your crimps and any soldered joints made properly (the HD wire will tend to eventually break strands and fail if it bends much though).

A burned connector is usually a result of the connector contacts being loose or the crimp to the wire being defective (typically as a result of an improper tool being used).

Comment: It might've been the fault of my inadequate crimp. I used a crimping tool, but it was my first time and I kind of just winged it.

Comment: @KI A good tool will hardly let you make a bad crimp, but good, professional level, tools tend to be expensive.

Comment: The wire does pull heat away from the connection. Often connector ratings are dependent on wire size. PP45 may not be rated for 45 Amps with 12 AWG wire. But I would bet on bad crimp, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the datasheet, the expected temperature rise over ambient with AWG 12 wire in a "multipole" configuration at 30 Amps is over 60 C (and literally off the chart).

So you probably do need to use 10 AWG wire to avoid over-heating your power pole connector. If you sustain 30 A, the 12 AWG wire will probably get pretty warm, especially if it is in a backpack. So it does seem like 10 AWG is better if you plan to sustain 30 Amps for more than a brief moment.

[image: Power Pole Data Sheet snippet]